# How set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on for MSsql pool on Glassfish

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, glassfish-4

How can I do this setup ?
I test with add property and put on the url ==> this not work

```
jdbc:sqlserver://myserver:xxxx;InitializationString=(set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER on);DatabaseName=mydatabase
```

I test with additionnal sql when connection is establish ==> this not work

Without this, I have a query error : Incorrect syntax near the keyword

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why do you think that there is a connection property `InitializationString` for the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver? It is not listed in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/setting-the-connection-properties?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: I lost first link I found but I fin another  : [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13157_01/wlevs/docs30/jdbc_drivers/mssqlserver.html](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13157_01/wlevs/docs30/jdbc_drivers/mssqlserver.html). If it's not a good property, I can image it didn't work. Do you know the correct keyword or url connection construction ?

Comment: Given that documentation 1) from Oracle and 2) says the protocol is `jdbc:bea:sqlserver:` it not about the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver, but probably about a driver that is (was?) included with WebLogic Server. I'm not aware of any such feature included in the Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver.

Comment: Thanks you, So it's not exiting a 'same' solution to set this parameter with JDBC ? Someone know if Is it possible to set it by sql command before sending the request or another way, I use JAVA and JPQL and the request contain column name same as MSsql keyword ?